# How to integrate gitext to VS 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, git-extensions

After I install it, it doesn't show up as a menu anywhere.

Am I missing something or does it not support vs2017?

Answer (score 8):

you should download and install VSIX

Temporary available here
https://mega.nz/#!S05nRBpR!jQL-JWUlIMzxKGtygjVStIJ5K8B8wUWEUb7Y8asIaCI

**EDIT:**
New link...

https://mega.nz/#!IzYSWKwB!jpO7Raj_4hi2aeiZ-RjweVFr_YkPdA6c2Zl9HdR7tD8

**EDIT 1/14/18:**
Now official, look @raghav answer

Comment: Thank you, but why is it not hosted on some more secure or at least expected location like github?

Comment: It's temporary, probably soon it will be in a permanent location. You can read more about it here https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/pull/3439

Comment: @MTZ4 can you please re-upload? The link is dead.

Answer (score 3):

Seems it has been official now.

Visual Studio plugin for using Git Extensions. VS 2017 supported too.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HenkWesthuis.GitExtensions

Answer (score 0):

I don't now why, but GitExtensionsVSIX.vsix provided in GitExtension release version 2.51.02, fails to install because it lacks some files inside. 
@raghav answer works, but it has older version (2.50.02 in 30\05\2018).
But GitExtensionsVSIX.vsix 2.51.02 could be fixed:

1. unpack GitExtensionsVSIX.vsix as it is zip archive.
2. add files manifest.json and catalog.json from contents of @raghav answer's GitExtensionsVSIX.vsix.
3. update version in that files to 2.51.02.
4. Update sha 256 hashes in manifest.json.
5. Add `<Default Extension="json" ContentType="application/json" />` to Types in [Content_Types].xml.
6. zip-pack all files.
7. rename extension to ".vsix".
8. Install.